# render scrape data in browser without storing in database

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

Is there any way to render the scrape data in the browser without storing in database.

code for scrape the data.

```
search = query.lower()
p_search = "-".join(search.split())
url = "xyz"+p_search
myurl = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
uReq = ureq(myurl)
uRead = uReq.read()
uReq.close()
soup = bs(uRead, 'lxml')
device_profile = soup.find('div', {'id': 'device-profile'})
return render(request, 'phone/device_profile.html', {'device': device_profile})
```

code to render the data in the browser.

```
{% if device %}

     {% for row in device %}

      {{ row }}

    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So what is the problem with your code?

Comment: code is working fine...i just want to render the data in HTML form...how it's showing in browser... [<h2 class="h3 blue">About Oppo Find X</h2>, <ol class="breadcrumb" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList"> <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"> <a href="https://www.kimovil.com/en/compare-smartphones" itemprop="item" itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing"> <span itemprop="name">All smartphones</span> <i></i> </a> <meta content="1" itemprop="position"/> </li> <li itemprop="itemListElement" ]

Answer (score 0):

So fill your template (`'phone/device_profile.html'`) with HTML as you prefer and use the templating. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="h3 blue">About Oppo Find X</h2>
<ul>
    {% for row in device %}
        <li>{{ row }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Update:

You need to understand the format of `device`. It looks like it is a list of strings. And the second string is the HTML string that you want to paste into template. So instead of for loop just pass needed element to the template:

```
return render(request, 'phone/device_profile.html', {'device': device_profile[1]})
```

and use it in the template directly:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ device }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately "not worked" is a very broad problem.

Comment: It is very hard to debug someone's code through StackOverflow knowing only the name of the exception. Try to print `device_profile`.